# I can't open many http websites on ubuntu

Tags: networking

Recently, I bought a new PC and installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. However I'm stuck in a really weird situation. It seems I cant open many http website in any browser and shell. Though I can access them withough any problem in my other devices. I did try some analysis but found nothing.

Now the current situation is this. I have access to internet by two different ISPs , and 4 devices:

New PC (Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 LTS): ISP1 => Cant open http websites properly. ISP2 => No problem

Old laptop (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) : No problem with both ISPs

Another laptop (windows 7) : No problem with both ISPs

Smartphone (android 5) : No problem with both ISPs

I tried to traceroute and ping the website with problematic ISP in my new PC and they are reaching correct destination.

curl output is: connection reset by peer.

Comment: please tell more about 'network1' and 'netword2'

Comment: @cmak.fr I clarified what I meant with network.